# Age of Empires II: Definitive Edition not running fluently using Proton on Ubuntu 20 LTS

Tags: ubuntu, nvidia, steam, games

I'm trying to run [Age of Empires II: Definitive Edition](https://store.steampowered.com/app/813780/Age_of_Empires_II_Definitive_Edition/) on Ubuntu Linux using Steam Proton. I enabled Proton in the latest stable 5.0.9 release. According to [the manual](https://github.com/ValveSoftware/Proton/wiki/Requirements), I have the latest avaliable drivers installed. The nvidia homepage lists 440.82 from 2020.4.7 as latest release.

```
# dpkg -l | grep nvidia-driver
ii  nvidia-driver-440
```

The game could be started and is running, but not liquid. It's jerkiny when e.g. I select some of the villagers and assign them to collect wood.

Graphics card:

```
# lspci -vnn | grep VGA -A 12
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: NVIDIA Corporation GK104 [GeForce GTX 660 Ti] [10de:1183] (rev a1) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] GK104 [GeForce GTX 660 Ti] [1462:2843]
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 37
    Memory at f6000000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16M]
    Memory at e0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=128M]
    Memory at e8000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=32M]
    I/O ports at e000 [size=128]
    Expansion ROM at 000c0000 [virtual] [disabled] [size=128K]
    Capabilities: [60] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [68] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [78] Express Endpoint, MSI 00
    Capabilities: [b4] Vendor Specific Information: Len=14 <?>
    Capabilities: [100] Virtual Channel
```

CPU is a `Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-4570 CPU @ 3.20GHz` with 32GB DDR3 memory. It seems unlikely related to the hardware, since it's more powerfull than the recommended requirements of the game. And I could even play it much more liquid on a notebook with onboard GPU.

Answer (score 1):

Found out that I have to enable *V-Sync* in the advanced graphic settings. Now the game runs much more fluent.